# HTML report formatting Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

I am generating a html report from my JMeter test. But the result table is very confusing. I have four throughput controller and inside i have one transaction controller for each. i ticked to generate parent sample as well. But when i generate report isee result by parent sample as well as
[image]

For example in the picture login is the transaction controller and login_page is the sampler. login_page sampler is inside the login controller. But i see result for both which is very confusing. Can you please help me this!!Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of the following options:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(login)(-success|-failure)?$
   ```

   it will instruct JMeter to display only `login` transaction in the HTML Dashboard
2. You can also tell JMeter to not to save subresults for Samplers in .jtl file at all, to do so add the next line to the aforementioned *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
- [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)